# Position element at the bottom of container without flex or position absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a component that uses both a background color for half of the component and
an image for the other half, with the image acting as an element with a margin. The problem I'm having is that I cannot use display flex to space elements correctly in the content area, it breaks the component with the current solution I'm using and I have no idea why.

I'm specifically trying to position .service__link at the bottom of .service__content. I've tried using paddings/margins to get it in place, but at smaller screen sizes it ends up overflowing out of the box.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.service-container {
    max-width: 1800px;
    margin-inline: auto;
    padding: 40px 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1.5rem;
}

.service {
    flex: 1 1 calc(33.3336% - 1.5rem);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #144088;
    min-height: 325px;
    border: 2px solid #144088;
    color: white;
}

.service::before {
    content: "";
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1645069258059-6f5a71256c4a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2076&q=80) left center/150%;
    shape-outside: polygon(79% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 42% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(79% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 42% 100%);
    shape-margin: .3em;
}

.service::after {
    content: "01";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    opacity: 25%;
}

.service__content {
    padding: 3rem 0 1rem 1rem;
    height: 100%;
}

.service__title {
    font-size: 26px;
}

.service__description {
    font-size: clamp(12px, 3vw + .25rem, 16px);
}

.service__title, .service__description {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.service__link {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 35%;
}

.service__link a {
    color: white;
}

.service__link img {
    filter: brightness(0)invert(1);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .service {
        flex: 0 1 518px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="service-container">
       <div class="service">
            <div class="service__content">
                <h4 class="service__title">Lorem</h4>
                <p class="service__description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat doloremque molestiae eligendi voluptas veniam repellendus, aperiam tempora suscipit consectetur sint?</p>
                <div class="service__link">
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/26/000000/image.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
            <div class="service__content">
                <h4 class="service__title">Lorem</h4>
                <p class="service__description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat doloremque molestiae eligendi voluptas veniam repellendus, aperiam tempora suscipit consectetur sint?</p>
                <div class="service__link">
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/26/000000/image.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
            <div class="service__content">
                <h4 class="service__title">Lorem</h4>
                <p class="service__description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat doloremque molestiae eligendi voluptas veniam repellendus, aperiam tempora suscipit consectetur sint?</p>
                <div class="service__link ">
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/26/000000/image.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

What is going on when display: flex is added to .service__content?

Also, if anybody has a better idea of how to make this component in general I'd love to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make `service__content` a flex column?

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah that causes it to jump out of it's container.

Comment: It shouldn't so there must something else going on.

Comment: @Paulie_D If I add `display: flex; flex-direction: column` to `service__content` and remove `float: right` from `.service::before` then it works as expected, but then I lose the background and text-wrapping effect that I want.

Comment: You bacground effect could be better managed without using pseudo- elements and clip paths. Why not use multiple backgrounds and a gradient?

Comment: I'll definitely try that out, I'm aware that the solution I used is pretty hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use this:
`position: absolute; bottom: 30px`
to put it in the bottom part of the div.

Comment: Well gee, I know I said without position: absolute because I was worried about text overlapping, but that only happens at an impossibly small screen size so this actually works fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you set service__link to flex instead of inline flex and add margin-top auto it should stay on the bottom

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you have to give `position : relative` for container

than for service__link `position: absolute;` `left:10px;` `bottom:10px;`
there will be no deterioration in smaller screen.

```
.service__content {
padding: 3rem 0 1rem 1rem;
height: 100%;
position: relative; // Added
}

.service__link {
display: inline-flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
width: 35%;
position: absolute; // Added
left:10px;          // Added
bottom:10px;        // Added    
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.service-container {
    max-width: 1800px;
    margin-inline: auto;
    padding: 40px 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1.5rem;
}

.service {
    flex: 1 1 calc(33.3336% - 1.5rem);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #144088;
    min-height: 325px;
    border: 2px solid #144088;
    color: white;
}

.service::before {
    content: "";
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1645069258059-6f5a71256c4a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2076&q=80) left center/150%;
    shape-outside: polygon(79% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 42% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(79% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 42% 100%);
    shape-margin: .3em;
}

.service::after {
    content: "01";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    opacity: 25%;
}

.service__content {
    padding: 3rem 0 1rem 1rem;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.service__title {
    font-size: 26px;
}

.service__description {
    font-size: clamp(12px, 3vw + .25rem, 16px);
}

.service__title, .service__description {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.service__link {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 35%;
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    bottom:10px;
}

.service__link a {
    color: white;
}

.service__link img {
    filter: brightness(0)invert(1);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .service {
        flex: 0 1 518px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="service-container">
       <div class="service">
            <div class="service__content">
                <h4 class="service__title">Lorem</h4>
                <p class="service__description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat doloremque molestiae eligendi voluptas veniam repellendus, aperiam tempora suscipit consectetur sint?</p>
                <div class="service__link">
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/26/000000/image.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
            <div class="service__content">
                <h4 class="service__title">Lorem</h4>
                <p class="service__description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat doloremque molestiae eligendi voluptas veniam repellendus, aperiam tempora suscipit consectetur sint?</p>
                <div class="service__link">
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/26/000000/image.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
            <div class="service__content">
                <h4 class="service__title">Lorem</h4>
                <p class="service__description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat doloremque molestiae eligendi voluptas veniam repellendus, aperiam tempora suscipit consectetur sint?</p>
                <div class="service__link ">
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/26/000000/image.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Content here.
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Try to put the particular CSS to the parent div, child div and footer div.